# How do I import and use a Java project with utils functions within a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

What is the best practice for this? I did some research and came across the use of shared library, but this is only for Groovy code. I have a massive Java project that I do not wish to convert to Groovy.

Comment: groovy based on java - so everything like in java. put your jar into a classpath and then you can import/call it from groovy.